# Azure data factory copy data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to get the same schema as my source dataset without creating it in the Azure database.

Can I get the same schema as the source data set without creating a table in an azure database while copying the data?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get the same schema as the source data set without creating a
>   table in azure data base while copying the data.

Copy activity needs real being input and output data source.If you want to get the schema, you have to set a real being dataset. It could not be limited to azure database, it could be some [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest) or on-prem [File system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system) which provides data schema.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand what do you mean.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any option or check boxes that i need to select while I am creating my sink data set so it takes the schema of the source data set.